# woocomerce localization does it override during update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, localization

A client requested I'd change some of woocomerce automatic localization translations. I understood it's manageable through woocommerce/i18n/languages/ but I'm worried it would change during a woocomerce version update.
So I guess the question is, do I have something to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

The location you reference is not safe as it is inside the plugin folder.

The [WooCommerce guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-9) states that the correct location for custom files is at `wp-content/languages/woocommerce`

This location should be safe from all WordPress updates, but you should still back up your site beforehand. That's just good practice.